# SSMS: "Generate change script" disabled even though option is enabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms

I added a few columns to a db table in SSMS v17.9.1. I went to right click on one of the new columns in order to "**generate change script**" but it was disabled. So, I went into the options and made sure this was checked....

**Tools > Options > Designers > Auto generate change scripts**

I restarted SSMS but it's still disabled. Any idea why? I created 3 columns and want to create a change script to add these columns to a production db.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is disabled or it is not there?

Comment: I enabled/checked "Auto generate change scripts". When I right click (in design) on the column the "generate change script" option is there, but disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why it's (Auto generate change scripts) still disable for you. I did like below and I'm able wo create change script..

Within SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) here is an option to automatically generate scripts for your changes done through the GUI. but by default this option that we will be disabled.

**To enable the option:**

```
From the SSMS menus click on "Tools"  
Click on "Options..."
Click on "Designers"
Check the checkbox "Auto generate change scripts" as highlighted below
```

After checking the specified checkbox, SSMS is now able to generate scripts for the creation and/or modification of any table when you use the designer.

**Testing this Out:**

Let's confirm the script generation for the creation of a new table.

- In SSMS select a database and expand the tree
- Right click on the tables folder inside and click on "New Table".
- A designer will appear for the creation of new table.
- Create a single column for this table, I have created a column named TestCol1 as nchar(10)
- Save the new table and give the table a name and click OK
- Another window will popup that includes the actual script for creating this new table as shown below:

Example:

[image]

- Click on "Yes" to save the script and you will be prompted to specify the location.  * The file name by default will be the name of the table such as "tableName.sql", but this can be changed to anything you like.

  - To prevent any potential data loss issues, you should review this script in detail before running it outside the context of the database designer.

    ```
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    SET ARITHABORT ON
    SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF
    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
    COMMIT
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    GO
    ALTER TABLE dbo.Table_1 SET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
    GO
    COMMIT
    select Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.Table_1', 'Object', 'ALTER') as ALT_Per, Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.Table_1', 'Object', 'VIEW DEFINITION') as View_def_Per, Has_Perms_By_Name(N'dbo.Table_1', 'Object', 'CONTROL') as Contr_Per
    ```
- If you do not want to save the script then click "No", clicking "No" will not roll back the implemented changes, but the script will not be saved.